# Color on screen area search

Tags: c#, screen, pixel, point

I'm trying to find patches of a certain color on the screen.

I am able to find all the pixels on the screen and test the RGB and add the points into an array, but i don't want all the pixels just 1 point for each patch of the color.

Here is my code:

```
    public static Point[] PixelSearch(Rectangle rect, Color Pixel_Color, int Shade_Variation)
    {
        ArrayList points = new ArrayList();
        Bitmap RegionIn_Bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        using (Graphics GFX = Graphics.FromImage(RegionIn_Bitmap))
        {
            GFX.CopyFromScreen(rect.X, rect.Y, 0, 0, rect.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        }
        BitmapData RegionIn_BitmapData = RegionIn_Bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, RegionIn_Bitmap.Width, RegionIn_Bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        int[] Formatted_Color = new int[3] { Pixel_Color.B, Pixel_Color.G, Pixel_Color.R }; //bgr

        unsafe
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < RegionIn_BitmapData.Height; y++)
            {
                byte* row = (byte*)RegionIn_BitmapData.Scan0 + (y * RegionIn_BitmapData.Stride);
                for (int x = 0; x < RegionIn_BitmapData.Width; x++)
                    if (row[x * 3] >= (Formatted_Color[0] - Shade_Variation) & row[x * 3] <= (Formatted_Color[0] + Shade_Variation)) //blue
                        if (row[(x * 3) + 1] >= (Formatted_Color[1] - Shade_Variation) & row[(x * 3) + 1] <= (Formatted_Color[1] + Shade_Variation)) //green
                            if (row[(x * 3) + 2] >= (Formatted_Color[2] - Shade_Variation) & row[(x * 3) + 2] <= (Formatted_Color[2] + Shade_Variation)) //red
                                points.Add(new Point(x + rect.X, y + rect.Y));
            }
        }
        RegionIn_Bitmap.Dispose();
        return (Point[])points.ToArray(typeof(Point));
    }
```

I call the method like this:

```
points = PixelSearch(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds, Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0), 15);
```

I sometimes get thousands of results from this and would only like a few. any ideas how i can do this?

Comment: In `if` expressions you use `&` - binary AND. but you need `&&`.

Comment: not answering the question, but i should change that. i have changed the code a bit since i asked the question already, but same results.

Comment: Without having to break apart the function and seeing what you're trying to do, can you explain what you mean by "1 point for each patch" ? You mean you only want 1 entry for any certain color? Or range of color?

Comment: its hard to explain. by patch, i mean an area with a certain color. so if there is a red circle on the screen, the entire circle should be 1 area so i want 1 point for that area.

Comment: Still having a slight issue understanding what you're wanting. Could you provide a sample image and a sample output that you're expecting?